# Replace Number in string in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to replace a number withing string since it can be done in regex but i don't know much about it here's my code

```
var rowNo=6;
var tName=jQuery(this).attr('name');
```

tName will be in this format

```
input_[3][InvoiceNo]
```

and I want to remove 3 and replace with `rowNo` value in regex 
what i tried was this

```
replace(/[0-9]+/, rowNo)
```

but this replaces all numbers with `rowNo`. I don't want to do that, what I want is to replace `3` with `rowNo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include `[]` to find string to be replaced

```
.replace(/\[[0-9]\]+/, "[" + rowNo +"]")
```

```js
var str = "input_[3][InvoiceNo_8_9]";    
var rowNo = 6;
str = str.replace(/\[[0-9]\]+/, "[" + rowNo +"]")
document.write(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace number inside `[]`

```
replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/, '['+rowNo+']')
```

```js
var str = 'input_[3][InvoiceNo]',
  rowNo = 4;
alert(str.replace(/\[[0-9]+\]/, '[' + rowNo + ']'));
```

Comment: hey that u misunderstood my question i want to replace all number within that bracket not 3

Answer (score 1):

Replace number with brackets,

```
var rowNo = 8;
var str = 'input_[3][InvoiceNo]';

alert(str.replace(/\[\d+\]/, '[' + rowNo + ']')); // returns input_[8][InvoiceNo]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ewdtv8L/